# Windows suddenly thinks I pressed the windows key all the time but i haven't

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, gaming, logitech-keyboard

> I have the problem that somehow all keys I press execute like I press the key with the Windows key.

Examples:

- If I press 'e' the Windows explorer opens
- When I press 'i' the settings open

It's like I pressed the 'win' key all the time, but I have definitely not pressed the Windows key

I already tried to press the key again that it disappears and searched the internet but I can't find something useful

It mostly happens when I play GTA V

I don't know if it's a Hardware problem or something else. I already reinstalled the Logitech G Hub, but the problem is still there.

And I can't work like that bc I have to restart my PC every time this happens

Specs:

- OS: Windows 10 Pro/21H1
- Keyboard: Logitech G 910
- Software: Logitech G Hub

I hope someone can help me because it's really annoying

Comment: Most probably you have stuck key. Try with another keyboard. Remove all other USB devices except your keyboard when you test.

Comment: @John sticky keys are disabled, and unfortunately I haven't a substitute keyboard

Comment: Try to clean below the key. Be careful.

Comment: @harrymc it's not a hardware problem because the key is fully up and after a restart of the OS it works perfectly without pressing the win key.

Comment: It's not a corrupt operating system.  If the key is sticking then it's a hardware problem with the keyboard.  Try using a different keyboard and see if the problem can be recreated with the non-functional keyboard disconnected. Repairing your operating system WILL NOT solve this problem.

Comment: GTA 3 is what I play and it turns Caps Lock on which is annoying..

Comment: Actually it's might not be a hardware problem. Many people asked the same problem in Microsoft Community. And Windows Key is the only one key which has this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a different keyboard or uninstall the keyboard drivers and reinstall them.

Comment: thanks i will try it later